# Access 2016 Subform select record to open other form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am writing a call program in access 2016. Customer need double click a record in subform. And open a pop up form to show that record. However, I got a problem on capture the selected record value. Below is the code for double click action and I got problem on ".AbsolutePosition = Me.optChooseBase - 1". Could you please help on that? Sorry for my fresh question. Thank you very much for your help!

```
With Me.Form.RecordsetClone
    **.AbsolutePosition = Me.optChooseBase - 1**
    varSomeVariable = .Fields("contact_SFDC_code")
End With


DoCmd.OpenForm "Call Table", _
    WhereCondition:="[contact_SFDC_code] = " & varSomeVariable, _
    WindowMode:=acDialog, _
    OpenArgs:=(Me.[Search SFDC Code Form])
```

Comment: Sorry missed the error message. "Method or data member not found"

Answer (score 0):

All you need should be:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Call Table", _
WhereCondition:="[contact_SFDC_code] = " & Me!contact_SFDC_code.Value & "", _
WindowMode:=acDialog, _
OpenArgs:=Me![Search SFDC Code Form].Value
```

or, if code a string:

```
WhereCondition:="[contact_SFDC_code] = '" & Me!contact_SFDC_code.Value & "'", _
```